# How to handle qt c++ with qml by keeping MVC architcture

Tags: qt, qml

I have a gauge.qml as shown below

**Gauge.qml**

```
Item {
    property real gaugevalue //this determine the gaugevalue.
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Rectangle {

        Image {
            x: 0
            y: 0
            source: "qrc:/gaugebg.png"
        }

        Image {
            x: 50
            y: 49
            source: "qrc:/needle.png";
            rotation: 0
            // I am doing some rotation logic with gaugevalue. please ignore logic for now
            transform: Rotation {
                origin.x: 10; origin.y:10;
                angle: gaugevalue
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Also, I have a main.qml as shown below, in which I have placed my gauge

**main.qml**

```
Window {
    id: main
    width: 640
    height: 480

    //gauge position
    property int gaugeX: 50
    property int gaugeY: 60

    Gauge {
        id : id_gauge
        gaugevalue : 50  //Now I am setting the gaugevalue from here. I need this to be controlled from my GaugeController class. 

        x:gaugeX
        y:gaugeY
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is make my code fit into MVC architecture. I am planning to write a 'GaugeController' class in C++ which will set the 'gaugevalue' (and more properties later). I really confused by reading many articles which leads to think in different way (I see many solution like using Q_PROPERTY or setProperty etc. (refer to this link : https://www.zhieng.com/exposing-qml-object-pointer-to-cc/). So It would be great if you could correct my code to achieve this in MVC architecture.

Answer (score 2):

using `qmlRegisterType<>()` and then create an instance of GuageController in your QML file which can be used to control Guage by passing values via  signals/slots

---

main.cpp

```
    qmlRegisterType<GaugeController>("myApp", 1, 0, "GaugeController");
```

---

main.qml

```
import myApp 1.0
...
GaugeController {
         id: id_controller

         // heres how you implment a method as a SLOT via QML
         onGaugeValueChanged(gaugeValue): {
            id_gauge.gaugeValue = id_controller.gaugeValue
          }
}
```

---

gaugeController.cpp

```
class GaugeController : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT


    // Q_PROPERTY MACRO allows the property to be read by QML
    Q_PROPERTY(int gaugeValue READ gaugeValue WRITE setGaugeValue NOTIFY gaugeValueChanged)

public: 


    int gaugeValue() { return _gaugeValue; };

signals:

    void gaugeValueChanged();
public slots:
    void setGaugeValue(newVal) { _gaugeValue = newVal; }

private: 

    int _gaugeValue;
```

---

**  EDIT **

from main.qml to pass parameters to  GuageController

```
 GaugeController {
       id: controller
       gaugeValue:  10
  }
  //  or

  function myfunction {   controller.gaugeValue = 5 }
```

Comment: I have a question, why we instantiating the 'GaugeController' from QML ? Can we instantiate it from C++ side ?

Comment: In your implementation, how to pass an argument to 'GaugeController' when we instantiate from QML side ? In C++ side, My GaugeController constructor have a parameter called 'ui_gauge_max'.

Comment: if you wanted to add  a property definition you would define a property on the c++ side with Q_PROPERTY  then use standard  QML  (see edit)

Comment: ... and we are creating the instance in QML because the controller has to have an interface to the view (gauge)  and if it is ccreated outside of the scope of the thing its controlling, they cant interact

Comment: .. you can also instance the object from c++  and then register it as a property in the QML Engine's root context http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html